# Debugging in SSIS- File load failure

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package to load from flat file to OLE DB destination. In between I have a Derived column which has 6 columns transformation out of total 15 columns being inserted in the OLEdb database table.

Problem: The file load is failing because a length of a column value in the file is greater than the datatype in the database for that column.

As there are million rows, how can I find out which column it is? I have added the error out put with redirect and created multi task and enabled data viewer. The only values its displaying are flat file source error output column (value =  Long text), error code, error column and error code description.

How can I have it display the actual value that's causing the issue?

Problem: The file load is failing because a length of a column value in the file is greater than the datatype in the database for that column.

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you are just trying to find the one line, I would import it manually into a staging table with all NVARCHAR(MAX) and then do a select where LEN(col) > the data type.  It will tell you what row has the bad data.